# How to land users to different page as per their roles

Tags: liferay

I am using Liferay and want to show different landing pages after users log in: If the admin of a portal try to login-in, he will land to page A and if a guest login into the portal he will login to page B.
@Today15 I have done this..

```
    package com.landing.page.pagetwo;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.LogFactoryUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.Action;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.ActionException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.PortalException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Log;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.struts.LastPath;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PrefsPropsUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PropsKeys;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.StringPool;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.Validator;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.WebKeys;
import com.liferay.portal.model.Group;
import com.liferay.portal.model.User;
import com.liferay.portal.service.GroupLocalServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil;

public class LandingPage extends Action {

@Override
public void run(HttpServletRequest httpsreq, HttpServletResponse httpsres)
              throws ActionException {
    try {
        doRun(httpsreq, httpsres);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ActionException(e);
    }
}
protected void doRun(
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {

        long companyId = PortalUtil.getCompanyId(request);

        String path =
            PrefsPropsUtil.getString(
                companyId, PropsKeys.DEFAULT_LANDING_PAGE_PATH);

        if (_log.isInfoEnabled()) {
            _log.info(PropsKeys.DEFAULT_LANDING_PAGE_PATH + StringPool.EQUAL +
                path);
        }

        if (Validator.isNull(path)) {
            path = getCustomLandingPage(request);
        }

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute(WebKeys.LAST_PATH, new LastPath(
            StringPool.BLANK, path));

    }
private String getCustomLandingPage(HttpServletRequest request)
        throws PortalException, SystemException {

        String customLandingPagePath = StringPool.BLANK;


        customLandingPagePath = getSitePath(PortalUtil.getUser(request), false);

        return customLandingPagePath;
    }
    private String getSitePath(User user, boolean includeLanguage)
            throws PortalException, SystemException {

            String sitePath = StringPool.BLANK;
            List<Group> userSites = getSites(user.getUserId());

            String language = StringPool.BLANK;

            if (includeLanguage) {
                language = StringPool.SLASH + user.getLocale().getLanguage();
            }

            if ((userSites != null) && !userSites.isEmpty()) {
                String siteFriendlyURL = userSites.get(0).getFriendlyURL();
                sitePath = language + "/group" + siteFriendlyURL + "/pagetwo";
            }

            return sitePath;
        }
    private List<Group> getSites(long userId)
            throws PortalException, SystemException {

            List<Group> sites = new ArrayList<Group>();

            for (Group group : GroupLocalServiceUtil.getUserGroups(userId)) {
                if (group.isRegularSite() &&
                    !"Guest".equalsIgnoreCase(group.getName())) {
                    sites.add(group);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return sites;
        }

        private static Log _log =
            LogFactoryUtil.getLog(LandingPage.class);
}
```

Now i can land on my site's custom page. but how to ristrict other user to land from this page, and how to land them to other page.

Answer (score 4):

First of all:
All Users are Guests, until the log in. Every authenticated user will have the "User" role. So you will have to check if the user is an Admin. Having said that, I would take this approach:
Create a Custom Field for the Role and call it landingPage for example.
Create a PostLoginHook.

```
package com.liferay.sample.hook;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.Action;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class LoginAction extends Action {
    public void run(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
        System.out.println("## My custom login action");
    }
}
```

In the run Method, you check for the value of the landingPage Custom Field, and then you set the lastPath property accordingly. Something like that for example:

```
Map params = new HashMap();  

params.put("p_l_id", new String[] {"PRI.1.1"});

LastPath lastPath = new LastPath("/c", "/portal/layout", params);

session.setAttribute(WebKeys.LAST_PATH, lastPath);
```

You may also want to take a look at the DefaultLandingPageAction class from Liferay itself:
https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/events/DefaultLandingPageAction.java

I would recommend the use of the custom field, so that you have the possibility to change the landing pages at all times. Another advantage would be, that you could do this with other roles as well.